# Is breaking out of an outer loop still applicable in Swift 2?

Tags: swift, loops, swift2, outer-join

I am reading the book, Professional Swift by Michael Dippery @ 2015. And in the book, on page 25, he writes:

**"Both break and continue statements break out of the innermost loops. However, you can label loops, which enables you to break out of an outer loop instead"**

```
let data = [[3,9,44],[52,78,6],[22,91,35]]
let searchFor = 78
var foundVal = false

outer: for ints in data {
    inner: for val in ints {
        if val == searchFor {
            foundVal = true
            break outer
        }
    }
}

if foundVal {
    print("Found \(searchFor) in \(data)")
} else {
    print("Could not find \(searchFor) in \(data)")
}
```

however, in playground when I change:

```
break outer
```

code to

```
break inner
```

The same result occurs:

Found `78 in [[3, 9, 44], [52, 78, 6], [22, 91, 35]]`

Is it still necessary to `label loops` to break out of an `outer loop`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Breaking inner and outer loop make difference lets check again with your code by taking one `updatedData` variable.

```
let data = [[3,9,44],[52,78,6],[22,91,35]]
let searchFor = 78
var updatedData = [Int]()
var foundVal = false

outer: for ints in data {
    inner: for val in ints {
        updatedData.append(val)
        if val == searchFor {
            foundVal = true
            break outer
        }
    }
}
```

In `break outer` you will get like :

> Found 78 in [[3, 9, 44], [52, 78, 6], [22, 91, 35]]
>
> updated data is [3, 9, 44, 52, 78]

In `break inner` you will get different updated data :

> Found 78 in [[3, 9, 44], [52, 78, 6], [22, 91, 35]]
>
> updated data is [3, 9, 44, 52, 78, 22, 91, 35]

So, you will check that in break inner after the 78 the 6 is not added to the updated data because inner loop is only breaked and again it stared with the next `ints`.

In break outer the whole loop will be breked.

Hope you will get help from this.

Comment: Actually, completely removing `break` wouldn't make a difference in the OP's code. That `break` is only an performance improvement.

Comment: Removing break statement will reflect in output. @Sulthan Then output should be like `[3, 9, 44, 52, 78, 6, 22, 91, 35]`